# Derivation of Henze/Baringhaus Goodness-of-fit statistic for Multivariate Normality

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, goodness-of-fit

In the paper *A Consistent Test for Multivariate Normality Based on the Empirical Characteristic Function*, Baringhaus and Henze define a test statistic,

$$T_n = n \int_{R^d} |\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n e^{it'Y_i} - e^{-\frac{1}{2}|t|^2}|^2 (2\pi)^{-d/2} e^{-\frac{1}{2}|t|^2}dt$$

and state that the integral is

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j,k = 1}^n e^{-\frac{1}{2} R_{jk}} - 2^{1- \frac{d}{2}} \sum_{j=1}^n e^{-\frac{1}{4} R_j^2} + n3^{-\frac{d}{2}}$$

Where $Y$ is the standardized sample, $Y = S^{-1/2}(X - \bar{X})$, and

$$ R_{jk} = (X_j - X_k)' S_n^{-1} (X_j - X_k) = |Y_j - Y_k|^2$$ 
$$ R_j^2 = (X_j - \bar{X} )' S_n^{-1} (X_j - \bar{X}) = |Y_j|^2$$

I am wondering if anyone can help me get started on the evaluation of the integral $T_n$?